# How can I write cross-platform folder paths in a .code-workspace file when Windows and UNIX use different file separators?

Tags: visual-studio-code, path

I have a VS code workspace which has a workspace folder. I originally set this up on windows and can use the workspace and the folder fine from there.

```json
  "folders": [
    {
      "path": "."
    },
    {
      "path": "..\\..\\Jekyll\\username.github.io\\_posts"
    }
  ],
```

When opening the workspace on a Mac there is an error that the workspace cannot be found. Updating the path to the workspace to use forward slashes rectifies the issue, but presumably the folder will not be found the next time I want to access this from Windows.

```json
  "folders": [
    {
      "path": "."
    },
    {
      "path": "../../Jekyll/username.github.io/_posts"
    }
  ],
```

Any ideas on how this can be made compatible for both Windows and Mac?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that Windows is perfectly happy with the forward slashes.

Furthermore, if adding additional folders to the workspace from Windows, paths with forward slashes are now used which means any future changes to the workspace with respect to folders should be compatible across both Mac and Windows.